# convert require js based js files to pure old style javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, ag-grid

I want to use [ag-grid-vue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-vue) in my web application that is ASP.net based and we have a huge ecosystem already built around pure javascript and custom frameworks. **I dont want to use Require js as it breaks our other JS scripts.**

I downloaded the package and opened a command prompt in the folder. Ran the following (as described in the weblink above)

```
To Build
npm install gulp -g
npm install npm-install-peers -g
npm install
npm-install-peers
gulp
```

After this the main.js file in the extracted folder looked like this :

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _agGridVue = require("./dist/agGridVue");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "AgGridVue", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_agGridVue).default;
  }
});

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

which is still require js based. ***All I want to do is , create a single/set of JS file/files so that I can load them in my  Web application (by using script tag ) without the introduction of Require JS in my code.***

Other ques : Is there anyway I could tell Require JS not to break the entire Web application that loads lot of pure JS scripts. Because its really frustrating.

Please tell me if im trying to do it in an incorrect way.

Comment: You use a build tool such as WebPack to do the transpiling along with the necessary Babel plugins. https://babeljs.io/

Comment: The code you show as problematic is not an AMD module. Judging by the information in your question and looking at the repo you link to, RequireJS is not a factor at all in the problem you are facing. Quite a few confused folks think that any and all usage of `require` entails that RequireJS is involved. But that's not the case at all.

Comment: @Louis agreed, lot of confusion over this side. now exactly where should i start. my question still remains the same. just want to load the grid and use it on my webpage